# Is it possible to put images as url in document

Tags: images

I am using WordPress version 4.8. Is it possible to add images via url in a document.

Comment: [Yes](https://en.support.wordpress.com/links/image-links/)

Comment: could you please say how? I couldn't find any 'insert from url' option in document.

Comment: There is [this link behind the "Yes"](https://en.support.wordpress.com/links/image-links/), which was the first thing that popped up when I searched the web for your question. Can you tell us, what exactly you tried already and what you're struggling with?

Comment: Its possible in page or posts. But I want to know whether its possible to have it in documents (from wp-document-revisions plugin)

Comment: I think its a no and just wanted to confirm it. I think I will go with the  posts.